# Aiogram send_message: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I made a small bot and during the launch process I encountered one error ***"[Errno 22] Invalid argument
"***, here is a piece of code due to which it occurs:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(message: types.Message):
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(GROUP_ID, message.from_user.id)
    if member:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, member)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str('Sorry !'))
```

The "if" line works well, the "else" line sends an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **drforse** said, you can fix it like this:
[github issue](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/349)

```
class DateTimeField(Field):
    """
    In this field st_ored datetime

    in: unixtime
    out: datetime
    """

    def serialize(self, value: datetime.datetime):
        print(value)
        if os.name == 'nt':
            timestamp = (value - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
        else:
            timestamp = value.timestamp()

        return round(timestamp)

    def deserialize(self, value, parent=None):
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value)
```